# How the message queues schedule works?

Tags: magento2, cron, message-queue, rabbit-mq

I just configured my message queues to run via RabbitMQ, but I don't know the schedule and frequency of these processes.

How could I check the schedule and change the number of processes to be executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default schedule is every minute, as you can see in this core file below.

```
<!-- /app/code/Magento/MessageQueue/etc/crontab.xml -->

<job name="consumers_runner" instance="Magento\MessageQueue\Model\Cron\ConsumersRunner" method="run">
    <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
</job>
```

- Re-running cron restarts the consumer.
- Each consumer processes 10000 messages and then terminates

To view a list of all consumers you can run:

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:list
```

You can edit your `env.php` to change the Consumers' runners and the amount to be executed.

```
'cron_consumers_runner' => array(
        'cron_run' => false,
        'max_messages' => 20000,
        'consumers' => array(
            'consumer1',
            'consumer2',
        )
    ),
```

Reference: [DevDocs - Manage Message Queues](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/mq/manage-message-queues.html)